# Cannot scroll in custom tab tag filter box

Tags: bug, user-interface, new-nav

1. I was on StackOverflow looking at a tag-filtered tab.
2. I already had more than could be displayed, but it listed them from the bottom.
3. Clicking on the list allowed me to scroll to the end and add a new one.
4. I then clicked save.

It won't stop looking like this:

[image: Image showing the bug]

I have tried:

- Switching (SO) tabs
- Refreshing the page
- Refreshing the page with cache bypass
- Closing the browser tab and opening a new one
- Closing the whole browser and re-openig
- Putting the cursor in the box and trying to move it left

Environment:

- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
- No user JS or CSS
- uBlock Origin